# console.log(JSON.parse(result)) prints [Object] where I expect to see JSON

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, google-maps-api-3

Given a string that is appears to be in valid JSON format (received from an api call), how can I parse that string such that I can get access to

The value of JSON.parse(data) comes back as JSON that contains [Object], which is not helpful to me.
**I'm trying to get the lat and lng out of `data` that is sent to me as a string that I *think* can be turned into JSON.**
I know I could just mess around with `data` as a string, but I want to use it as JSON.

```
{ results: 
   [ { address_components: [Object],
       formatted_address: 'Google Bldg 41, 1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy, Mountain View, CA 94043, USA',
       geometry: [Object],
       place_id: 'ChIJxQvW8wK6j4AR3ukttGy3w2s',
       types: [Object] } ],
  status: 'OK' }
```

Here is the value of data:

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Google Building 41",
               "short_name" : "Google Bldg 41",
               "types" : [ "premise" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "1600",
               "short_name" : "1600",
               "types" : [ "street_number" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Amphitheatre Parkway",
               "short_name" : "Amphitheatre Pkwy",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Mountain View",
               "short_name" : "Mountain View",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Santa Clara County",
               "short_name" : "Santa Clara County",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "California",
               "short_name" : "CA",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "United States",
               "short_name" : "US",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "94043",
               "short_name" : "94043",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Google Bldg 41, 1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy, Mountain View, CA 94043, USA",
         "geometry" : {
            "bounds" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 37.4228642,
                  "lng" : -122.0851557
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 37.4221145,
                  "lng" : -122.0859841
               }
            },
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 37.4224082,
               "lng" : -122.0856086
            },
            "location_type" : "ROOFTOP",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 37.4238383302915,
                  "lng" : -122.0842209197085
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 37.4211403697085,
                  "lng" : -122.0869188802915
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJxQvW8wK6j4AR3ukttGy3w2s",
         "types" : [ "premise" ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Comment: If this question isn't a duplicate, I'll be amazed, but I cannot find it's twin anywhere.

Comment: It does parse the JSON as expected, it just that you don't see the whole of it when you log it to the console, because the log function is limiting how deep it goes into the object to print values.

Comment: omg... I should have thought of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get lat and lng like this:

```
parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
lat = parsedData.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
lng = parsedData.results[0].geometry.location.lng;
```